# How to replace certain strings?

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

Example of my text file:

```
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/0/48/2.png,206,1514
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/1/46/3.png,206,5796
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/2/45/4.png,206,2252
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/3/46/78.png,200,7208
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/4/45/43.png,206,2252
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/5/46/8.png,200,7208
...
```

In this text I must replace number after `base/` following this rules:

```
if that_number=0 then that_number=5
if that_number=1 then that_number=6
if that_number=2 then that_number=7
if that_number=3 then that_number=8
if that_number=4 then that_number=9
if that_number=5 then that_number=10
```

Wanted result:

```
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/5/48/2.png,206,1514
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/6/46/3.png,206,5796
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/7/45/4.png,206,2252
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/8/46/78.png,200,7208
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/9/45/43.png,206,2252
03/Oct/2016:06:39:50-0500,cd/base/10/46/8.png,200,7208
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: `if (0 <= that_number && that_number <=  5) that_number += 5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` would work:

```
sed \
    -e 's/base\/1/base\/6/' \
    -e 's/base\/2/base\/7/' \
    -e 's/base\/3/base\/8/' \
    -e 's/base\/4/base\/9/' \
    -e 's/base\/5/base\/10/' \
    -e 's/base\/0/base\/5/'
```

I think you have to put the "base/0" case last, otherwise, the 5 -> 10 case kicks in as well.

Comment: It's also important (as you have done) to have the 5→10 case after the 1→6 case; otherwise, 5 will be replaced by 10 *which will then be replaced by 60*.

Answer (score 3):

In Perl it's easy to both match the context *and* do the addition:

```
perl -pe 's,base/\K\d+,$& + 5,e' input_file
```

We match anything of the form `base/<numbers>`, forget about the first part (up to the `\K`), and replace the rest with whatever was matched (`$&`) plus 5. `e` makes the replacement a Perl expression instead of just a string.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` can make use of the fact that its a `+5` operation on each number:

```
awk -F'/' '{$5+=5 ; print}' OFS='/' input_file
```

When using `/` as filed delimiter for input (`-F'/'`) and output (`OFS='/')`, respectively, 5 needs to be added to field number 5.

Note that the slashes' positions and numbers are crucial here.